# HibernateSearch: Whenever I restart, I get this error?

Tags: spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate search orm (5.5.4 final) and lucene (5.5.4 final) for indexing.

When I start server normally everything is works fine, but when I restart server I get this error.

```
2019-11-13 10:16:30|APP_COUNTRY_IS_UNDEFINED|x|2.4.0-SNAPSHOT|x-int|main|DEBUG|o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment|Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
2019-11-13 10:16:30|APP_COUNTRY_IS_UNDEFINED|x|2.4.0-SNAPSHOT|x-int|main|INFO|c.j.c.h.b.dao.jpa.config.JpaConfig|creating entity manager factory
2019-11-13 10:16:35|APP_COUNTRY_IS_UNDEFINED|x|2.4.0-SNAPSHOT|x-int|main|ERROR|o.s.boot.SpringApplication|Application startup failed
2019-11-13 10:16:35|APP_COUNTRY_IS_UNDEFINED|x|2.4.0-SNAPSHOT|x-int|main|ERROR|o.s.boot.SpringApplication|Application startup failedxorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [x/dao/jpa/config/JpaConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
        at com.x.x.boot.Main.main(Main.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:587)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager named 'x.x..dao.domain.KafkaLog'
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:260)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:513)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManagers(IndexManagerHolder.java:482)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:358)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:199)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchIntegratorBuilder.buildSearchIntegrator(SearchIntegratorBuilder.java:117)
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:532)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000252: Unable to initialize directory provider org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider for index x.x..dao.domain.KafkaLog
        at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.create(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:230)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.spi.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createIndexManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:256)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Cannot write into index directory: . for index x.x..dao.domain.KafkaLog
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.getVerifiedIndexPath(DirectoryHelper.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.DirectoryHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryHelper.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.spi.BaseDirectoryProviderService.initialize(BaseDirectoryProviderService.java:64)
        ... 45 common frames omitted
```

I have changed the permission of my directory and have given write access for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to set the root directory for indexes, and Hibernate Search defaults to storing indexes in the JVM's working directory (whatever it is).

Set the property `hibernate.search.default.indexBase` to a directory you know the application will have write access to, and this should go away. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-configuration-directory for more information about configuring the directories.

Regarding the fact that it worked the first time... I would assume something was different the first time. Maybe Hibernate Search was disabled, or you started the application from another directory? Anyway, the real problem is most likely related to access rights.

Comment: It works every time, when I shut down and start the server again.
But the error comes only when I restart the server using restart command in Linux.
Also I changed the access rights of directory but the problem persists same.